# lbmethod_heartbeat:notice - No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor --error after installing apache2.4.2

Tags: apache

On starting the webserver the error_log shows

```
[Wed May 16 03:48:53.027372 2012] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1114:tid 3075385024] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed May 16 03:48:53.028312 2012] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1114:tid 3075385024] AH00489: Apache/2.4.2 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 16 03:48:53.028351 2012] [core:notice] [pid 1114:tid 3075385024] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd'
```

apache configuration:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-deflate --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-proxy-http --with-included-apr
```

I am getting Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server error

This is the error generated in error_log

```
[Wed May 16 03:49:20.116317 2012] [authz_core:error] [pid 5015:tid 2946440000] [client 127.0.0.1:59386] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/gowtham/webSites/ferry/
```

is this error because of lbmethod_heartbeat:notice ??

or there is a permissions misconfiguration on DocumentRoot directory?? but the  directive's configuration is taken from a working webserver, so I think there r no mistakes in  block. N i even tried giving

```
chown -R [apache_user:apache:group] /home/Necktwi/webSites/ferry
```

and /home/Necktwi got chmod -R 766

thanq

Comment: I know this is an old question, but since it is still open, please post some relevant configuration information (e.g. files in conf/ folder such as httpd.conf and/or the sites-enabled subfolder). The "configuration" you listed in your original question was only the configuration for the compilation of Apache httpd, not its runtime configuration, which controls behavior such as which requests require authentication.

Comment: BTW, this question is probably more suitable for ServerFault than it is for StackOverflow since it is more about server administration than programming.

Comment: i totally gave up compiling the apache and i abandoned the project. how to port this question to serverfault?

Comment: I think a moderator would have to move it, but if you were still looking for the answer you could post over there then update here with a link. Since you are no longer looking for an answer you should close this question (you can accept my answer if you want or just delete the question, I believe).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 16):

These messages are unrelated. It is common to encounter the "AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor" message (which is not actually an error) but still have a functioning server.

Usually, you can suppress that message by commenting out the heartbeat load-balancer method module from httpd.conf (unless, of course, you are actually using it). It [has been suggested](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201211.mbox/%3C1162516276.8579887.1353080461144.JavaMail.root@consol.de%3E) that this be disabled in the default configuration, but evidently it is not yet.

```
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
```

It is possible that there is a problem with one of the authentication or authorization modules which is causing the server to deny requests. You might try disabling the modules beginning with "auth" in `httpd.conf` as well as any restrictions that you have in your configuration.